# php showing logout button only if logged in

Tags: javascript, php, html

I am writing the code for a simple website where users log in and out and some other basic functions. I would like it to be so when anyone logs in, a logout button  is shown on all the pages they visit, and hidden if they are not logged it. I am still new and cannot figure out what is wrong. The logout button appears as soon as i initially click the login button, but when i navigate to other pages the button disappears from my menu.

menu.php

```
$currentfile = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']);
if($currentfile = basename($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'])){
    if (isset($_SESSION['ID'])) {
        echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Home</a>
        <a href=\"viewlist.php\">See Reviews</a>
        <a href=\"example11.php\">Write a Review</a>
        <a href=\"search.php\">Search</a>
        <a href='logoutconfirmation.php'>Logout</a>
        <hr />";
    }else{
        echo "<a href=\"index.php\">Home</a>
        <a href=\"viewlist.php\">See Reviews</a>
        <a href=\"example11.php\">Write a Review</a>
        <a href=\"search.php\">Search</a>
        <hr />";
    }
} ?>
```

index.php

```
<?php
    include "header.inc.php";
    $pagetitle= "Login Form";
    $showform =1;
    $errormsg =0;
    $errorusername = $errorpassword = "";
    $inputdate = time();

    //FIRST CHECK TO SEE IF THE USER IS LOGGED IN
    if(isset($_SESSION['ID']))
    {
        echo "<p class='error'> You are already logged in. </p>";
        include_once "footer.inc.php";
        exit();
    }
    if(isset ($_POST['submit'])) {

        /*************************************************************
        * ALL FIELDS- STORE USER DATA; SANITIZE USER-ENTERED DATA
        *************************************************************/
        $formfield['username'] = trim($_POST['username']);
        $formfield['password'] = trim($_POST['password']);

        if (empty($formfield['username'])) {
            $errorusername = "The username is required.";
            $errormsg = 1;
        }
        if (empty($formfield['password'])) {
            $errorpassword = "The password is required.";
            $errormsg = 1;
        }

        if ($errormsg != 0) {
            echo "<p class='error'> THERE ARE ERRORS!</p>";
        } else {
            //get the user data from the database
            try {
                $user = "SELECT * FROM Users WHERE username =:username";
                $stmt = $pdo->prepare($user);
                $stmt->bindValue(':username', $formfield['username']);
                $stmt->execute();
                $row = $stmt->fetch();
                $countuser = $stmt->rowCount();

                // if query okay, see if there is a result
                if ($countuser < 1) {
                    echo "<p class='error'> *This user cannot be found in the 
 database* </p>";
                } else {
                    if (password_verify($formfield['password'], $row['password'])) {
                    $_SESSION['ID'] = $row['ID'];
                    $showform = 0;
                    header("LocationL confirm.php?state=2");
                    echo "<p> Thank you for logging in! </p>";
                } else {
                    echo "<p class='error'> The username and password 
combinations you entered are not correct. Please try again! </p>";
                }
            }//username exists
        } catch (PDOException $e) {
            echo 'ERROR fetching users: ' . $e->getMessage();
            exit();
        }
    }
}
if($showform == 1) {
    ?>
    <p class="homemsg">Welcome to the Movie Review Hub! Feel free to look 
around or sign in to write your own review.</p>

    <form name="login" id="login" method="post" action="index.php">
        <table class="center">
            <tr>
                <th><label for="username">Username: </label></th>
                <td><input name="username" id="username" type="text" placeholder="Required Username"
                   }?><span class="error" <?php if (isset($errorusername)) {
                echo $errorusername;
            } ?></span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <th><label for="password">Password: </label></th>
        <td><input name="password" id="password" type="password" placeholder="Required Password"
                   }?><span class="error"> <?php if (isset($errorpassword)) {
                echo $errorpassword;
            } ?></span></td>
        <tr>
            <th><label for="submit">Submit: </label></th>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" id="submit" value="submit"/></td>
        </tr>
    </table>


    <p><a href=index.php>Register.</a></p>

    <?php
    include_once "footer.inc.php";
}
?>
```

Like I said i would like the logout button to be show on all of the pages if someone logs in from the index page, the menu is included in all of my files

The logout button initially shows when i press the login button, but when i refresh the page or navigate to another page it goes away.

Comment: Where's your `session_start` call ...?

Comment: I would just like to take a moment to give you praise - it's very rare to see a "very new" programmer actually using good practices like PDO and prepared queries, and using `password_verify` for handling passwords. Good job.

Answer (score 0):

Like @CBroe mention, try add `session_start` at start of every page.

Better create config file, put it there and include everywhere.

Comment: I added a session_start to my config file and that fixed half of my problem! Now I just need to figure out how I can make it so my logout button appears on all of my pages ONLY if someone is logged in. I tried doing this in my menu file but its not working.

Comment: try do var_dump($_SESSION) to see what you get